# How to calculate reverberation time in Android?

Tags: android, audio, frequency

I´m trying to develop an app that calculates the reverberation time of a room and displays it on the screen. 
What I´ve done so far is:

- record the audio in a wav file
- extract the bytes from the wav file and transform them to "double"
- plot the data obtained following the next equation: SPL=20log(samples/ 20 μPa)
- then from the figure that I´ve plotted, I can obtain the RT60 easily

The point is that I´m not really sure if what I´m doing has any sense, as wherever I search for info I see that they obtain the RT by octave ( or third of octave ) bands and in my case I´m not doing anything with the frequency, I´m just plotting the graph against time getting something like this:

[image: RT]

So my point is, is there anything that I´m missing?
Should the "samples" value in the SPL formula be something else? What Im doing to obtain them is:

```
double audioSample = (double) (array[i+1] << 8 | array[i] & 0xff)/ 32767.0;
```

and then I place the [-1,+1] values that I obtain directly in the formula

For what frequency I´m I theorically plotting the RT?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a common frequency for the voice you can use 500hz
, 1000 or 2000. Or an average of the 3 like for the calculus off rt60. Oliver.

Comment: welcome, this is more of a comment than an answer. An answer shows the user specifically how they can resolve their issue. please review [answer]